# Google analytics in WPF web browser control causing error

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, wpf, google-analytics

I have WebBrowser control in my WPF application. I am loading several different pages into it. Each one has Google Analytics tracking code. Sometimes when I am refreshing (loading) same content I am getting this error:

[image]

**Translation:**

```
There is an error in script at this site
Wiersz = Row
Znak = Sign
Błąd = Error
Kod = Code
Do you want to continue runnig scripts at this site?
Yes/No
```

EDIT: 
This page is not reachable from outside. This is only available in company LAN. Can it be the reason?

Comment: How long are you waiting before you refresh? I suspect that its not done running that's why you are getting the error.

Comment: There is no pattern. I can refresh after 0.5s and there is no error and sometimes error is appearing after few minutes